# How to defined event in jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

when myclass1 is slideUp, I want to hidden myclass2.
i need to live or trigger in jquery.

```
$('.myclass1').slideUp();

$('.myclass1').on('slideUp' ,function() {
 $('.myclass2').hide();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

`slideUp` isn't an event. If you look at the docs you'll see the second argument it accepts is a callback function, which is executed after the animation has finished. Try this:

```
$('.myclass1').slideUp(400, () => $('.myclass2').hide());
```